# Relationship: belongs to only for filtered result

Tags: laravel, orm

I have 2 models: subscribe and user

Model subscribe contains accept and user_id field. This model belongs to user model. And now - I want to make model function which in first step filter only accept subscribe and second step display users. I don't have idea how can I do that. I know that I can make this method in user model but is it possible to make this function inside subscribe model?

I tryed do like that but it doesn't work. Any idea?

```
public function activeSubscribes() {
    $instance = $this->where('user_id', 1)
                     ->belongsTo(User::class);
    return $instance;
}
```

Comment: I think you would do it at the user level,  User::activeSubscribes()    use the belongs to method where the subscription belongs to the user

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add in your user model this code

```
public function activeSubscribes()
{
    return $this->whereHas('subscribes', function ($q){
        $q->where('accept', 1); //your condition
    });
}

public function subscribes()
{   //Also maybe you need hasOne relation
    return $this->hasMany(Subscribes::class);
}
```

Then you can use it like this

```
User::activeSubscribes()->get()
```